# Get-PnPList not working correctly with subsite's subsite

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, powershell, pnp-powershell, script

I am using below code to get lists of all subsites. But it is failing after one level of sitecollections. i cant connect with each web using Connect-PnPOnline as it takes too much time. Please suggest how to get lists of all subsites.

```
$webs= Get-PnPSubWebs -Recurse

foreach ($web in $webs)
{
write-host $web.Url -ForegroundColor Cyan
$sublists = Get-PnPList -web $web 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to make sure your account has proper permission on the site collection.

Then, you can use the following cmdlets to get all subsites of the site collection and all lists of these subsites:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/Wendy -Credentials (Get-Credential)

$webs=Get-PnPSubWebs -Recurse
foreach($web in $webs)
{
write-host $web.Url -ForegroundColor Cyan
$sublists = Get-PnPList -web $web 
$sublists
}
```

My result is:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try below mention code

```
$webs= Get-PnPSubWebs -Recurse

foreach ($web in $webs)
{
   $SubWebs = Get-PnPSubWebs -Identity $web.Title -Recurse
   foreach ($Subweb in $SubWebs)
   {
      write-host $Subweb.Url -ForegroundColor Cyan
      $sublists = Get-PnPList -web $Subweb 
   }
   write-host $web.Url -ForegroundColor Cyan
   $sublists = Get-PnPList -web $web 
}
```

Comment: it is giving below error  for some of the webs                                                                                                       
Get-PnPSubWebs : File Not Found.

Comment: You need to use this line `Connect-PNPonline -Url $subweb.Url -Credentials $cred
`

Comment: still same error coming Get-PnPSubWebs : File Not Found.
At line:38 char:19
+     $SubSubWebs = Get-PnPSubWebs -Identity $web.Title -Recurse
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Get-PnPSubWebs], ServerException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.GetSubWebs